# Reverse incremental search in Cshell

Tags: bash, shell, full-text-search, tcsh, bash-completion

I am using Cshell at the office, and it does not seem to have reverse incremental search for history. Is there any way to enable `reverse-i-search` (like the one in bash) in cshell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume you're using `tcsh` (`csh` doesn't have much in the way of history search at all).

You can bind the command `i-search-back` to some key (it's not bound by default).  It seems to be similar to bash's `reverse-i-search`.

See the description in the [tcsh man page](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Editor_commands.html).

For example, I have

```
bindkey ^X/ i-search-back
```

in my `$HOME/.cshrc`.

Comment: If you prefer using bash, you can probably change your default shell.  `man chsh`.  Or you can probably just invoke `bash -l` from your [t]csh prompt.